# Detecting no key press in c++

Tags: c++, linux

I have tried various methods such as getchar(), kbhit(), and getch() to write a program that records the key pressed and not pressed at regular time intervals, but find a way to detect when the key is not pressed Could not. How can I detect unpressed state?

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <fstream>
#include    <chrono>
#include    <ctime>
#include    <string>
#include    "getch.h"


...

    fileName += to_string(localTime->tm_year + 1900) + monStr + 
        dayStr + "_" + hourStr + minStr + secStr;

    while(loopState)
    {
        readFile.open(fileName);
        loopState = readFile.is_open();
    }
    writeFile.open(fileName);

    while(true)
    { 
        currentClock = clock();
        if(currentClock % 100 == 0)
        { 
            /* if(getch() == ' ')
                cout << "1";
            // code here
            */
        }
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: if you knew which key was pressed you definately know which was not (period).

Comment: What is `getch.h`?

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows I'm afraid that there is no way to do such thing. If you were on Linux you could use the `ncurses` library which should allow you to keep track of  `key press` and `key release` events (although only a key at a time).

Comment: @MircoDeZorzi *Assuming you're using Windows I'm afraid that there is no way to do such thing.* – Why do you think so? Short: You are wrong.

Comment: @Swordfish Oh woops, I just noticed the tags, by bad. But wasn't `getch.h` a common getchar implementation for Windows?

Comment: @MircoDeZorzi Maybe it reminds you of `conio.h` which became popular with Borland/Inprise. But of course it's possible to get each key's state using the win32 apis.

Comment: Maybe this question can be salvaged if you edit it and explain _what_ you are trying to achieve.